# PyAudio Doesn't Handle Long Periods of Silence

Tags: python-3.x, speech-to-text, pyaudio

I'm trying to use PyAudio (http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#sources) to record data from a microphone. However, whenever there are long periods of silence (over 20 or 30 seconds) it fails - it just quits working without throwing an exception or error.

Even during silent periods the stream is constantly firing the callback, so I'm wondering if that is causing an issue. I tried putting an rms filter, but even during periods of silence the rms value may be high or higher than the rms value when someone is speaking into the microphone.

I want to be able to leave the program running in the background indefinitely and have it record audio whenever someone speaks.

I'd like help with:

1. Writing this code to handle long periods of silence and continue to work (indefinitely)
2. Is there a better way to determine if someone is actually speaking than the rms calculation?

Code below. Thanks!

```
def rms(data):
    d = np.frombuffer(data, np.int16).astype(np.float)
    return np.sqrt((d*d).sum()/len(d))

def process_audio(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    if rms(in_data) > 200:
        DOSTUFF

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000
CHUNK_SIZE = 512

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = audio.open(
    format=FORMAT,
    channels=CHANNELS,
    rate=RATE,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK_SIZE,
    stream_callback=process_audio
)

stream.start_stream()

try: 
    while stream.is_active():
        time.sleep(0.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    audio.terminate()
```